# Simple MongoDB Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, pipeline, aggregation

I'm a bit confused on how to group using aggregation but still be able to extract specific values from arrays:

```
    db.collection.aggregate([
    {   "$unwind": f"${stat_type}" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$userId",
            "value" : { "$max" : f"${stat_type}.stat_value" },
            "character" : f"${stat_type}.character_name", <-- how do I extract this value that matches where the $max from above is grabbed.
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "value": -1 }},
    { '$limit' : 30 }
    ])
```

Sample Entries:

```json
{
  'name' : "Tony",
  'userId' : 12345,
  'damage_dealt' : [
    "character_name" : "James", 
    "stat_value" : 100243
  ]
}
{
  'name' : "Jimmy",
  'userId' : 12346,
  'damage_dealt' : [
    "character_name" : "James",
    "stat_value" : 1020243
  ]
}
{
  'name' : "Tony",
  'userId' : 12345,
  'damage_dealt' : [
    "character_name" : "Lebron",
    "stat_value" : 99900243
  ]
}
```

A sample output for what I'm looking for is below:

```json
[
  {
    '_id':12345, 
    'user' : 'Tony'
    'character_name' : 'Lebron', 
    'stat_value' : 99900243 
  },
  {
    '_id':12346, 
    'user' : 'Jimmy'
    'character_name' : 'James', 
    'stat_value' : 1020243 
  }
]
```

Comment: Please update some sample documents, and the corresponding output you are expecting

Comment: Added some sample input/output @CharchitKapoor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$top`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/top) accumulator to achieve the desired result. Like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$damage_dealt"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userId",
      "value": {
        $top: {
          output: {
            character_name: "$damage_dealt.character_name",
            stat_value: "$damage_dealt.stat_value"
          },
          sortBy: {
            "damage_dealt.stat_value": -1
          }
        }
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      character_name: "$value.character_name",
      stat_value: "$value.stat_value"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "stat_value": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 30
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vt6A3Tm2BCs).

Or collects all the group elements in an array, and the max `stat_value`, then pick the object from the array containing the max stat_value.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$damage_dealt"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userId",
      "max_stat": {
        "$max": "$damage_dealt.stat_value"
      },
      "damages": {
        "$push": {
          name: "$name",
          damage_value: "$damage_dealt"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "damages": {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$damages",
              "as": "damage",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$damage.damage_value.stat_value",
                  "$max_stat"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "character_name": "$damages.damage_value.character_name",
      "stat_value": "$damages.damage_value.stat_value",
      "name": "$damages.name"
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "stat_value": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 30
  }
])
```

Playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bDxHVvuj3eK).

Comment: Is there a simpler way to do this via grouping alone, similar to the format I was using.

Comment: Here also, I am grouping the records, it's just that I am using a different accumulator function. We can change the grouping to push all elements of a group in an array, and then find out the element in the array with max stat_value. But this is cleaner. If this operator is not present on your mongodb. Let me know.

Comment: Yeah I get an unknown group operator error: `pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: unknown group operator '$top', full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': "unknown group operator '$top'", 'code': 15952, 'codeName': 'Location15952'}`

Comment: That looks pretty good, any way to extract the name along with that data like the sample output as well?

Comment: Updated the query

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you could do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$userId",
      "user": {"$first": "$name"},
      "damage_dealts": {"$push": "$damage_dealt"},
      "maxStat": {"$max": {"$first": "$damage_dealt.stat_value"}}
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "outChar": {
        "$first": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$damage_dealts",
            {"$indexOfArray": ["$damage_dealts.stat_value", "$maxStat"]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "user": 1,
      "character_name": "$outChar.character_name",
      "stat_value": "$outChar.stat_value"
    }
  },
  {"$sort": {"stat_value": -1}},
  {"$limit": 30}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lOFcjeOJMZm).